# Contrasts in linear mixed model with repeated measurements in SPSS

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, spss, contrasts

I am currently building a linear mixed model with repeated measurements in SPSS. My syntax is:

MIXED measurement BY female **mediansplit time** WITH age

/CRITERIA=DFMETHOD(SATTERTHWAITE) CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1)

SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE)
PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)

/FIXED=female **mediansplit time** age **mediansplit*time** | SSTYPE(3)

/METHOD=ML

/REPEATED=time | SUBJECT(study_id) COVTYPE(AR1)

/**TEST=’mediansplit over time 0 vs 1’ mediansplit -1 1.**

Meadiansplit = 2 levels (0 & 1),
Time = 7 levels (0-6)

To find out if there are differences between the two groups of the **mediansplit over time** I want to calculate ANOVA-style contrasts. To my knowledge this is the /TEST command in SPSS for LMM (last line of my syntax). However, when running the above model, I get the warning **“Custom hypothesis test 1 (mediansplit over time 0 vs 1) will not be performed because the L matrix is not estimable”.**

So, my question is: how do I have to adjust the /TEST command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As mediansplit has only two levels you get the outcome of the significance test from the Fixed Effect table and if you request the estimated marginal means tables /EMMEANS=TABLES(mediansplit) you get the same in terms of a t-test.

The error occurs as soon as you specify an interaction in the /fixed statement. It should work if you omit the interaction.

I encountered the same problem with a test on a specific contrast for a seven-level factor, where I wanted to test the mean of the first four levels against the mean of the other three levels and I never found a solution with the /TEST command.  I eventually created a set of orthogonal contrast variables for the whole fixed model and entered them as covariates that included the one that I was interested in.